# How to run a docker image with the same time zone as the host machine?

Tags: docker

How to tell docker to run any image to pick the time zone settings for the host machine.

This is necessary especially when dealing with time zone related data.

Comment: [Related answer](https://serverfault.com/a/683651) on serverfault.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the TZ environment variable to the same as the host like this

```
docker run --rm -e TZ=$(cat /etc/timezone) debian date
```

This sets the TZ environment variable to the content of the /etc/timezone file of the host machine.

The above command runs the `date` command on a `debian` image to show that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try using environment variables.

with the docker run command:

```
docker run -e TZ=America/Los_Angeles <containername>
```

or in the docker file (you may or may not have to install tzdata, depends on the system):

```
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ America/Los_Angeles
```

Comment: This answers how you would set the timezone for a given container, but does not address how to get the host's timezone or how to apply that timezone to all containers.